# Update Else Insert - Informatica

Tags: oracle, merge, insert-update, informatica

I have two tables identical tables with data from different sources. These tables must now be merged. Both these tables do not have any primary keys

I need to merge on table 2 T2 with data in table 1 T1

Update T2 when data matches on following columns in T1

T2.f_id = T1.f_id and T2.r_id = T1.r_id and T2.date = T1.date

else Insert data from T1 into T2

There are 50+ more columns of numeric data type with values 1's and 0's and '[NULL]'

When I tried merging the data, Updates went fine.

But for the inserted rows, all the T2.f_id, T2.r_id and T2.date column values were [NULL] but the values in other columns got inserted fine

Can someone help where I am going wrong

I am using Informatica. Using lookup on T2(target) and Update startegy to update or insert

Comment: You can just debug the mapping, and see what is happening. Maybe some ports are not connected or something. It is hard to speculate without seeing the mapping!

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling the wrong ports from the lookup transformation. Make sure your ports from the source T1 is set to input/output in the lookup and this is the one connected to the insert flow of the mapping.